# segmentaition fault in openmp Linux

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, openmp

I am just learning openMp recently,and when I compiled and ran the following program on Linux,I met a "SEGMENT FAULT".Could anyone heip me to solve it?

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <omp.h> 

 void Hello(void); /* Thread function */ 

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {     
  /* Get number of threads from command line */     
 int thread_count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10); 

 # pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count)    
 Hello(); 

  return 0; } /* main */ 

  void Hello(void) {     
  int my_rank = omp_get_thread_num();     
  int thread_count = omp_get_num_threads(); 

  printf("Hello World from thread %d of %d\n", my_rank, thread_count); 

  } /* Hello */
```

Comment: You ran it with a number as parameter, right?

Comment: Yes ,and it was my first time program on Linux,I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to launch the executable with an argument corresponding to the number of threads:

```
g++ -fopenmp test.cpp -o myExec
./myExec 4
```

Otherwise you have to hardcode the thread_count variable, for example:

```
 int thread_count = 4
```

Then you won't need any argument.